# Sitecore (6.4.1) workbox link

Tags: sitecore

I'm using Sitecore version 6.4.1

I have a scheduled task that sends notification mail to content approver and I want to provide a url link to Workbox in the email. Could someone tell me how the workbox URL looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can login to Sitecore backend in Content Editor mode, and switch the bottom tab to Workbox. The URL string in the browser will change to what you need.

It contains a number of query string parameters. You can play with them finding out how each combination influences the Workbox appearance.